# Flutter moor insert hangs on isolate

Tags: sqlite, flutter

When I create a database I want to initialize it with a ton of data.

I have the following initialization service.

```
// This needs to be a top-level method because it's run on a background isolate
DatabaseConnection _backgroundConnection() {
  // construct the database. You can also wrap the VmDatabase in a "LazyDatabase" if you need to run
  // work before the database opens.
  final database = VmDatabase.memory();
  return DatabaseConnection.fromExecutor(database);
}
Future<void> _initDatabase(Map<String, dynamic> args) async {
  var moorIsolate = await MoorIsolate.spawn(_backgroundConnection);
  var connection = await moorIsolate.connect();
  var db = BillingDatabase.connect(connection);
  _initBillingSpecialties(db, args["specialties"]);
}

Future<void> _initBillingSpecialties(BillingDatabase db, String specialtiesJson) async {
  var json = jsonDecode(specialtiesJson);
  var jsonSpecialties = json["specialties"] as List<dynamic>;
  var specialities = jsonSpecialties.map((s) =>
      DbSpecialtiesCompanion(name: Value(s["specialty_name"]),
          mohNumber: Value(s["moh_specialty"]))).toList();
  return db.specialtyDao.saveAllSpecialties(specialities);
}

@injectable
class InitDbService {

  Future<void> initDatabase() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    var specialties = await rootBundle.loadString("lib/assets/billing_specialties.json");
    compute(_initDatabase, {"specialties": specialties});
    //initDbSync(specialties);
  }

  Future<void> initDbSync(String specialtiesJson) async {
    var json = jsonDecode(specialtiesJson);
    var jsonSpecialties = json["specialties"] as List<dynamic>;
    var specialities = jsonSpecialties.map((s) =>
        DbSpecialtiesCompanion(name: Value(s["specialty_name"]),
            mohNumber: Value(s["moh_specialty"]))).toList();
    var dao = GetIt.instance.get<SpecialtyDao>();
    return dao.saveAllSpecialties(specialities);
  }
}
```

`initDbSync` runs and inserts just fine. While `db.specialtyDao.saveAllSpecialties(specialities);` never actually exectues any SQL. I have it printing log statements for the moment so I can see what it's doing.

Update: I found out that VmDatabase.memory(logStatements: true); was needed to see the SQL. I can see it printing the statements.

I'm running on a simulator so I can look at the raw db file. And there's nothing there. When I query in the app there's also nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

So what's not really clear in the documentation is that `VmDatabase.memory();` opens up a new database in memory. Not takes the database from memory.

You want to take your reference to the file that you pass in the constructor, and use

```
VmDatabase(File(dbFile));
```

then it will actually run on your sql.